In Azure Communication Services I am receiving "request body validation error". See property 'x-ms-acsemail-geoforward-acsarmresourceid
Using .NET nuget package Azure.Communication.Email method EmailClient.Send, emails are being successfully delivered, but I get this error:

Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Request body validation error. See property 'x-ms-acsemail-geoforward-acsarmresourceid'
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
ErrorCode: BadRequest
Content:
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Request body validation error. See property 'x-ms-acsemail-geoforward-acsarmresourceid'","target":null,"details":null,"innererror":null}}
Headers:
mise-correlation-id: REDACTED
x-ms-error-code: REDACTED
api-supported-versions: REDACTED
X-Cache: REDACTED
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
X-Azure-Ref: REDACTED
Date: Sat, 29 Jun 2024 21:53:45 GMT
Content-Length: 178
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8


Also getting the same error with the azure package in python. Hopefully someone can provide solution for this.

A lot of people seem to have been hit with this issue over the weekend. I've updated the latest NuGet package (1.0.1) but this has not fixed this issue.
I believe the email is still sent, it's the call to "WaitForCompletionAsync" that's causing the problem

Contacted Azure Media and Communication Services Support:
The issue you are facing is caused by a known issue and the product team is working to deploy a fix.
Despite receiving the error described in the Issue Description (as above), the emails are being successfully delivered.

I raised the issue with support, this morning they thought it was a transient issue which was resolved but it is still occurring, they are aware of this and investigating
